# Pointer to non-composite literal

Tags: go

Is there an established pattern for getting pointers to non-composite literals?

```
x := 5
y := &x
```

The above code works, but is awfully verbose.

Comment: I don't see what can be shortened in this code. You want the pointer to the variable x?

Comment: I'm also not sure how this can get much more concise.

Comment: "Awfully verbose"? I _never_ _ever_ had to write such stuff...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly that the only point of `x` is to allocate the `int`, I recommend something even more "verbose":

```
y := new(int)
*y = 5
```

I don't see getting it any shorter than what you have. Since the `&` operator [requires](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) its operand to be either addressable or a composite literal, you're either stuck doing what you're doing to get something addressable, or you can do what I suggest and avoid the `&` altogether.

Comment: If it's a common enough type, it is possible to wrap it in a function with something like
    `func intPtr(i int) *int { return &i }
    func main() {
        y := intPtr(5)
    }`

http://play.golang.org/p/bIOUAua2b5